# mouseout in select option jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox and a combobox. I wanna textbox hide and combobox show when I "mouseover" to go textbox. And then textbox show and combobox hide when "mouseout" combobox. But I can't because it can't move mouse in option of select.

```
<input type=text name="textbox" id="textbox">
<select id="combobox">
<option value = 1>1</option>
<option value = 2>2</option>
<option value = 3>3</option>
</select>
```

and JavaScript:

```
$("#combobox").mouseout(function(){
$("#combobox").hide();
$("#textbox").show();
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain your problem? Your code seems to accomplish what you ask.

Comment: yes! Even mouseover for combobox it ready. But i want select a value in combobox is not working. Combobox will be hide.

Comment: Ok, that's better. So you want to show the combobox as well. When should it pop up?

Comment: I want to show it until I mouseout from combobox. But I can not select in each option. When i use mouseout event

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout()` to delay the show/hide functions to determine if the user has `mouseover`ed the `<option>`s:

```
$(function () {

    //create a variable to store a reference to a timeout
    var box_timer;

    //bind an event handler for the `mouseout` event to the `#combobox` element
    $("#combobox").mouseout(function(){

        //set a timeout to hide the `#combobox`, show the `#textbox`, and set the value of the `#textbox` to the value of the `#combobox`
        box_timer = setTimeout(function () {

            //hide the `#combobox` and get it's value
            var box_val = $("#combobox").hide().val();

            //show the `#textbox` and set it's value
            $("#textbox").val(box_val).show();
        }, 100);

    //bind event handler to the `mouseover` event for the `#combobox` element
    }).mouseover(function () {

        //clear the timer because the user has move the cursor from a `#combobox > option` element to the `#combobox` element
        clearTimeout(box_timer);
    });

    //bind an event handler for the `mouseover` event on the `#textbox` element
    $("#textbox").mouseover(function(){
        $("#combobox").show();
        $("#textbox").hide();

    //bind an event handler to all the `<option>` elements on the `mouseover` event
    }).children().mouseover(function (event) {

        //clear the timer because the user has move the cursor from a `#combobox > option` element or the `#combobox` element
        clearTimeout(box_timer);

    //bind an event handler to all the `<option>` elements on the `mouseout` event
    }).mouseout(function () {

        //set the timer to do the same thing as `mouseout`ing the `#combobox` element
        box_timer = setTimeout(function () {

            //trigger a `mouseout` event on the `#combobox` element
            $('#combobox').trigger('mouseout');
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/FNx2B/

Comment: I can't click on the combobox.

Comment: oh opps! i don't want to get value of combobox and send for textbox when i'm not click. Can you help me. One more

Comment: ok! i will to edit 'var box_val = $("#combobox").hide().val();

            $("#textbox").val(box_val).show();
' to ' var box_val = $("#combobox").hide();
        $("#textbox").show();'